# What implications does having a zero eigenvalue in a covariance have?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

I have several different covariance matrices, and have found the set of eigenvalues for each of them. I noticed that each matrix has one eigenvalue that is zero. This seems like a pattern. Do covariance matrices always have one and only zero-eigenvalue? Why not two? Why not none?

Comment: Yes, zero is non-negative. What do you mean?

Comment: Do you have a specific distribution in mind? Are you talking about sample or population covariance matrix?

Comment: In general there is no restriction.  Any real positive semidefinite (symmetric) matrix can be the covariance matrix of a set of random variables.

Answer (score 0):

In each of your cases, there exists a deterministic linear or affine relation between your variables.

For example this would arise if your variables were "price of X in in the USA in dollars" and "price of X in the USA, expressed in yen", for various commodities X.  Or if they were "distance to vacation spot Y in miles" and "distance to vacation spot Y in kilometers", for various places Y.  Or, more interestingly, "proportion of students at school Z studying maths ",
"proportion of students at school Z studying chemistry", and  "proportion of students at school Z studying anything else", for various schools Z.

Comment: for the example of "proportion of students at school Z studying maths ", "proportion of students at school Z studying chemistry", and "proportion of students at school Z studying anything else", what would the positive eigenvalues mean, and what would the zero eigenvalue mean?

Comment: The 3 proportions add up to the constant 1; the vector of coefficients $(1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector of the CV matrix corresponding to eigenvalue $0$.